# Cannot connect to dockerized Postgres through dockerized pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ayyy
        POSTGRES_USER: letsgo
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwpwpwpw22
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@example.com
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pwpwpwpw1
    ports:
      - "5433:80"
```

(I changed the environment variables to not spoof my credentials)

However I am unable to connect to my Postgres server through pgAdmin. pgAdmin is using reverse proxy from port 5433 to my subdomain `pgadmin.domain.com`. I am also reverse proxying HTTP from pgAdmin's container into HTTPS. (I do not know if that could be an issue)

This is the error I get:

> Unable to connect to server:
> connection to server at "db" (192.168.32.3), port 5432 failed: timeout expired

If I use `localhost` as a hostname, I get this:

> Unable to connect to server:
> connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed:
> Connection refused    Is the server running on that host and accepting
> TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port
> 5432 failed: Address not available    Is the server running on that host
> and accepting TCP/IP connections?

UPDATE: I am not even able to ping the containers between each other. The service name is correctly resolved to IP, but I get no response.

Comment: Just use service name here db as the hostname for database. Docker has its own internal DN which will resolve service name to correct docker IP. Additionally if you don't need to expose the database to the outside world you can remove 5432 port as long as your service share the same network.

Comment: When I use "db" as a hostname I get the "timeout expired" error. I am not sure if I need to add docker's ip to the postgres' pg_hba.conf file in order to get rid of the error or if increasing timeout time would be enough - I incread it to 1 minute and the issue persists.

Comment: Normally, you don't need to add any IP in postgres config. Could you show how you configured connection to your db in pdadmin. This is probably where your problem resides. You also needs the dB to listen to * to be able to serve outside it's container.

Comment: pgAdmin v6.1, Create Server tab: Connection host: db, Port: 5432, Mainteance database: postgres, Username: letsgo, Password: pwpwpwpw22. I also noticed that although both the containers are in the same network I am not able to ping each other - I am not really experienced with docker so I am not sure if that is intended behaviour or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was even unable to open ports on my server, so I reinstalled it. Everything works as it should since then.